# Собачьи команды

Tags: этимология

Любой собачник знает набор стандартных команд для собак, среди которых есть вполне понятные, вроде "сидеть", "лежать", "рядом" и "голос", но есть и такие, значение которые приходятся просто запоминать не только собакам, но и людям, например: "апорт", "фас". Есть еще устаревшие, вроде "анкор" или "тубо", которые сейчас не употребляются.

А что это, собственно, за слова? Просто набор звуков, удобный для запоминания собакой, или иностранные слова?

Answer (score 3):

Апорт от французского apport - принести. Фас - от немецкого fassen - хватать,
анкор от французского encore - еще, это в цирке, от непонимания, а вообще  от ancor - якорь по английски - держать.
Тубо - французский - tout beau  дословно  все красивые, потише... это когда собака суетится и делает неположенное, аналог нельзя, более широко - сидеть, лежать, место.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, команда **ТУБО** означает что-то типа НЕЛЬЗЯ, чаще звучит в виде просто ФУ!. У Вл. Маяковского: "...*сказав  **тубо**, собакам озверевшей страсти.*". Здесь  налицо   аналогия с этнографическим понятием ТАБУ, как нечто запретно-неприкасаемое у туземцев. А первоисходник - в иврите: **טָאבּוּ** звучит, как **табу** или **табв**/**w**/. Что касается команды **АНКОР**, то хорошо бы точно узнать, что она означает сейчас, и совпадает ли это сегодняшне значение с первоначальным, - в собачьих командах могла появиться путаница. Если значение этой команды типа ЕЩЁ / ПОВТОРИ / ДУБЛИРУЙ, то это соответствует французскому **encore** - ЕЩЁ (такая команда используется и в цирке у жонглёров). Но, если значение этой команды типа более распространенного - ЧУЖОЙ, то здесь необходимо привлечь иврит: **נֵכָר** - в современном прочтении это звучит, как н э х а р, но может быть почтено по-буквенно, как **НКР** = [а]**НК**[о]**Р** (буквы: нун **נֵ** /н/, каф **כָ** /к, х/, реш **ר** /р/; *иврит читается справа-налево*); в переводе означает ЧУЖЕЗЕМЕЦ, ЧУЖБИНА. Ранее, в своём ответе на вопрос "Что такое Полкан?", я уже писал о том, что к собачьим кличкам приложили руку ашкеназы.

Comment: Вы б еще туборг сюда притянули за уши, Надо ж идиш с ивритом попутать, טָאבּוּ - на идише табу, а в иврите его нема, этого слова, ему там неоткуда взяться 2000 лет назад.   
Про собак, а кроме как прыгать, команда "еще" зачем?   
А вот держать - необходима - стеречь, чтоб не сбежал.
А вы сами по-русски прочтите н э х а р чуть иначе.

Comment: @fatyalink. В переводе с иврита טָאבּוּ табу означает ЗАПРЕТ (в широком смысле). Можете найти в ИРИС-словаре по ссылке http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php . Отсюда и этнографический термин ТАБУ, и собачья команда ТУБО. Что касается собачьей команды АНКОР, то я же сразу оговорил, что нужно выяснить её значение. В Интернете я такую информацию не нашёл.

Comment: Вы его в словаре 18 века поищите, когда еще в Полинезию не ходили. А то в современной латыни -да на гугле и не то найти можно.

Comment: бомбарда - obruam - Венеция,  не иначе, Абрам постарался.